# `if (Date >= Date1 && <= Date2 ){do this}` dosn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code changes the `new Date()` to DayHourMinute
e.g. `monday9AM45minutes` to `010945`
What I use is `010945` and my code specifies
if the var is between  `>=010921 && <=011010`
change the `background` to green `else` nothing

But nothing happens and if I use `alert(Time)` it gives the message `010945`.

How can if fix this?

Code:

```
function one() {
    now = new Date();
    hour = "" + now.getHours();
    if (hour.length == 1) {
        hour = "0" + hour;
    }
    minute = "" + now.getMinutes();
    if (minute.length == 1) {
        minute = "0" + minute;
    }
    day = "" + now.getDay();
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    var Time = day + '' + hour + '' + minute;
    if (Time >= 010835 && Time <= 010920) {
        document.getElementById('Man1').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man1').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 010921 && Time <= 011010) {
        document.getElementById('Man2').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man2').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011011 && Time <= 011105) {
        document.getElementById('Man3').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man3').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011106 && Time <= 011155) {
        document.getElementById('Man4').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man4').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011156 && Time <= 011239) {
        document.getElementById('Man5').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man5').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011240 && Time <= 011325) {
        document.getElementById('Man6').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man6').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011326 && Time <= 011415) {
        document.getElementById('Man7').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man7').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011416 && Time <= 011505) {
        document.getElementById('Man8').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man8').style.background = '';
    }
    if (Time >= 011506 && Time <= 011555) {
        document.getElementById('Man9').style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Man9').style.background = '';
    }
}
setInterval(one, 1000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X58D5/)

Comment: Computers are not humans. You can't just omit whatever seems implied to you, and expect them to just figure it out like a human would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time is a string, and you are comparing to an int.  Put the values in quotes:

```
if ( Time>='020000' && Time<='030000' ){
```

Comment: worked in jsfiddle.
I am currently having troubles uploading files to my web-host so the soon as i test it online il set this as Answare.